# agregar cadena a cadena existente mysql

Tags: mysql, nodejs, npm

### Problema:

la pregunta es bastante especifica, tengo una columna de seguidores, en donde los separo con un guión ej: juan-jesus-jose-admin-yifo... el problema es si por ejemplo el usuario tiene a juan de seguidor, y jesus quiere tambien ser seguidor de esa persona, no se como hacer para que al juan ya existente se le agregue -jesus y quede asi: juan-jesus...

intente poniendo esto: `UPDATE usuarios set seguidores= seguidores + '-${usuario}' WHERE usuario = '${usuario}`

pero no sirve :C .... porfavor si alguien me puede ayudar plis :D

Comment: Eso viola las normalizacion de la base de datos y no deberia hacerse asi. deberias tener otra tabla que mantenga esas relaciones... Dicho esto, que error te da esa query?

Comment: simplemente se añade un 0... entonces me recomiendas tener una tabla con los seguidores, que este relacionada no(?

Comment: eso es lo que correponde.. porque por ejemplo, imaginate el lio para sacar un seguidor de esa lista? o si queres saber todas las personas a las que sigue alguien? como vas a hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depende de  como lo planifiques...
deberias tener una tabla (Personas).. con los Campos:

```
id....Persona...
```

y otra tabla (Seguidores) con sus seguidores...con los Campos:

```
id.....idPersona....Seguidor.......
```

Y en una consulta, buscas los seguidores de esa persona y con la función CONCAT los juntas....

eso se me ocurre.....creo que es lo más lógico....

Comment: asi es, estoy viendo tutoriales de relacionar tablas, cosa que nunca me ensaeñaron y no sabia que se podia :c